# Using Gekko to reproduce a control history in an observed trajectory

Tags: python-3.x, ode, nonlinear-optimization, gekko

I am trying to get Gekko to reproduce the bank angle history from the Apollo 10 reentry event.  I have altitude, velocity, and latitude state histories and the actual NASA bank angle data for comparison.  My path constraints look like this:

```
m.Minimize(1e3*(r_desired-r)**2)
m.Minimize(1e6*(V_desired-V)**2)
m.Minimize((lat_desired-phi)**2)
m.Minimize(0.5*bank**2)
```

Couple of questions:

1. Did I implement the path constraint correctly?  Is there a smarter way to do that?
2. I am getting a converged solution but for the life of me I cannot get the bank angle to match.  It gets pretty close at times (especially if you consider 180=-180) but definitely off at other times.  Any recommendations on how to get better agreement?

I have tried tons of different combinations and iterations to include weighting the constraints, using linear interpolation vs using a polynomial fit for the historical data, turning on and off other constraints, limiting the bounds on the bank angle, etc.  Any help would be very appreciated.  Thanks!

Code and state history data are below.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import pandas as pd

pi = math.pi
#======================================#
#OPTIONS
#======================================#
rotating_earth = 0 #### 0 = 'no' 1 = 'yes'####


#======================================#
#Gekko setup
#======================================#
m = GEKKO() # initialize GEKKO
tfin    = 200
nt      = 201 #simulation time is 2500 seconds
gekkoTime = np.linspace(0,tfin,nt) #time array
m.time = gekkoTime

#======================================#
#Params
#======================================#
r_earth     = m.Param(value=6378.137) #radius of the earth
g0          = m.Param(value=9.80665/1000) #acceleration of gravity
ro_s        = m.Param(value=1.225e9) #atmospheric density at sea level
beta        = m.Param(value=0.14) #inverse scale height
omega       = m.Param(value=0) #rotation of the earth, rad/sec
mass        = m.Param(value=5498.2) # mass at reentry
S           = m.Param(value=12.02e-6) #reference area km^2
Cl          = m.Param(value=0.4082) #coefficient of lift
Cd          = m.Param(value=1.2569) #drag
CS          = m.Param(value=Cl) #coeff of sideslip

T       = m.Param(0)           #N, thrust of satellite
pcsi    = m.Param(0)           #rad, "Vertical" thrust vector angle
epsilon = m.Param(0)           #rad, "Horizontal" thrust vector angle

#======================================#
#Initial Conditions
#======================================#
#States at entry 
Re = 6498.270 #km
flp_e= -6.6198381*(pi/180) #flight path angle at entry 
psi_e = 18.0683*(pi/180) #heading angle 
V_e = 11.06715 #velocity km/sec
theta_e = 174.24384*(pi/180) #longitude east
phi_e = -23.51457*(pi/180) #latitude south 


if rotating_earth == 1: # if the rotating Earth is turned on
    V_e   = m.Param(10.6589) #entry Velocity, km/sec
    flp_e = m.Param(-6.87459*pi/180) #initial flight path angle
    psi_e = m.Param(19.9425*pi/180) #initial heading angle
    Azi_e = m.Param(psi_e+(pi/2-2*psi_e)) #intial azimuth angle
    omega = m.Param(value=7.2921159e-5) #rotation of the earth, rad/sec


#======================================#
#Variables
#======================================#

# #state variables
# r = m.Var(value=Re, lb=6378.137, ub=Re)
# V = m.Var(value=V_e, lb=0, ub=V_e)
# phi = m.Var(value=phi_e, lb=-90*pi/180, ub=70*pi/180)   #latitude
# theta = m.Var(value=theta_e, lb=-pi, ub=pi)             #longitude
# flp = m.Var(value=flp_e, lb=-90*pi/180, ub=10*pi/180)
# psi = m.Var(value=psi_e)

#state variables
# r = m.Var(value=Re, lb=6378.137, ub=Re)
# V = m.Var(value=V_e, lb=0, ub=V_e)
# phi = m.Var(value=phi_e, lb=-25*pi/180, ub=-13*pi/180)   #latitude
# theta = m.Var(value=theta_e, lb=150*pi/180, ub=220*pi/180)             #longitude
# flp = m.Var(value=flp_e, lb=-90*pi/180, ub=10*pi/180)
# psi = m.Var(value=psi_e)

#state variables
r = m.Var(value=Re)
V = m.Var(value=V_e)
phi = m.Var(value=phi_e)   #latitude
theta = m.Var(value=theta_e)             #longitude
flp = m.Var(value=flp_e)
psi = m.Var(value=psi_e)

#control variables
bank    = m.MV(value=0, lb=-180*pi/180, ub=pi)    # bank angle, rad
# bank    = m.MV()    # bank angle, rad
bank.STATUS = 1

#===============================#
#APOLLO HISTORICAL DATA
#===============================#

apolloAlt = np.array(pd.read_excel('ApolloData.xls', sheet_name="Altitude"))
apolloVel = np.array(pd.read_excel('ApolloData.xls', sheet_name="Velocity"))
apolloLat = np.array(pd.read_excel('ApolloData.xls', sheet_name="Latitude"))
apolloBank = np.array(pd.read_excel('ApolloData.xls', sheet_name="Bank"))


def lin_interp(gekkoTime, ApolloData):
    return np.array(np.interp(gekkoTime, ApolloData[:,0], ApolloData[:,1]))

# alt_desired = lin_interp(gekkoTime, apolloAlt)
# r_desired   = alt_desired+r_earth.value
Vel_desired = lin_interp(gekkoTime,apolloVel)
# lat_desired = lin_interp(gekkoTime,apolloLat)
bankTime = np.linspace(0,500,2000)
bank_desired = lin_interp(bankTime,apolloBank)

#curve fit
x1 = apolloAlt[:,0]
y2= apolloAlt[:,1]
p30 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1, y2, 30))
alt_desired = p30(gekkoTime)
r_desired = alt_desired+r_earth.value


# x1 = apolloVel[:,0]
# y2 = apolloVel[:,1]
# p30 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1, y2, 30))
# # Vel_desired = p30(gekkoTime)

x1 = apolloLat[:,0]
y2 = apolloLat[:,1]
p30 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1, y2, 30))
lat_desired = p30(gekkoTime)

path = m.Param(value=alt_desired)

#======================================#
#Intermediate Variables
#======================================#
g = m.Intermediate(g0*(r_earth/r)**2) #calculate gravity
ro = m.Intermediate(ro_s*m.exp(-beta*(r-r_earth))) #calculate ro
D = m.Intermediate(((ro*Cd*S)/2)*V**2) #calculate drag
L = m.Intermediate(((ro*Cl*S)/2)*V**2) #calculate lift
# error = m.Intermediate(m.abs3(path-r))

#======================================#
#EQUATIONS OF MOTION
#======================================#
m.Equation(r.dt() == V*m.sin(flp)) #calculate r.dt()

m.Equation(theta.dt() == (V*m.cos(flp)*m.cos(psi))/(r*m.cos(phi))) #calculate theta .dt()

m.Equation(phi.dt() == (V*m.cos(flp)*m.sin(psi))/r) #calculate phi .dt()

m.Equation(V.dt() == (T/mass)*(m.cos(pcsi)*m.cos(epsilon))-(D/mass) - g*m.sin(flp)+r*omega**2*m.cos(phi)\
    *(m.cos(phi)*m.sin(flp)-m.sin(phi)*m.sin(psi)*m.cos(flp))) #calculate V.dt()

m.Equation(flp.dt() == ((T/mass)*(m.sin(pcsi)*m.sin(bank)+m.cos(pcsi)*m.sin(epsilon)*m.cos(bank))+(L/mass)\
    *m.cos(bank)-g*m.cos(flp)+((V**2)/r)*m.cos(flp)+2*V*omega*m.cos(phi)*m.cos(psi)+r*omega**2*m.cos(phi)\
    *(m.cos(phi)*m.cos(flp)+m.sin(phi)*m.sin(psi)*m.sin(flp)))/V) #calculate flp .dt()

m.Equation(psi.dt() == ((1/(mass*m.cos(flp)))*(T*(m.cos(pcsi)*m.sin(epsilon)*m.sin(bank)-m.sin(pcsi)\
    *m.cos(bank))+L*m.sin(bank))-((V**2)/r)*m.cos(flp)*m.cos(psi)*m.tan(phi)+2*V*omega\
    *(m.sin(psi)*m.cos(phi)*m.tan(flp)-m.sin(phi))-((r*omega**2)/m.cos(flp))*m.sin(phi)\
    *m.cos(phi)*m.cos(psi))/V) #calculate psi .dt()

# m.Equation(r.dt() == V*m.sin(flp)) #calculate r.dt()
#
# m.Equation(theta.dt()*(r*m.cos(phi)) == (V*m.cos(flp)*m.cos(psi))) #calculate theta .dt()
#
# m.Equation(phi.dt()*(r) == (V*m.cos(flp)*m.sin(psi))) #calculate phi .dt()
#
# m.Equation(V.dt() == -D/mass-g*m.sin(flp)) #calculate V.dt()
#
# m.Equation(flp.dt()*V == ((L/mass)*m.cos(bank) - g*m.cos(flp)+((V**2)/r)*m.cos(flp))) #calculate gamma .dt()
#
# m.Equation(psi.dt()*V == ((L*m.sin(bank))/(mass*m.cos(flp))-((V**2)/r)*m.cos(flp)*m.cos(psi)*m.tan(phi)))  #calculate psi .dt()

#======================================#
#Optimize
#======================================#
p = np.zeros(nt) # mark final time point
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)
r_desired= m.Param(value=r_desired)
V_desired= m.Param(value=Vel_desired)
lat_desired = m.Param(value=lat_desired*pi/180)

# m.Minimize(final*r)
# m.Minimize(error)
# m.Minimize(.5*bank**2)
# m.Minimize(m.abs(r_desired-r))
m.Minimize(1e3*(r_desired-r)**2)
m.Minimize(1e6*(V_desired-V)**2)
m.Minimize((lat_desired-phi)**2)

m.Minimize(0.5*bank**2)
# m.Minimize(m.abs(bank))

# m.options.MAX_ITER=1000
m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()

#======================================#
#Plotting
#======================================#
alt         = np.array(r.value)
alt         = alt-r_earth.value
vel         = np.array(V.value)
latitude    = np.array(phi.value)*180/pi
longitude   = np.array(theta.value)*180/pi
fpa         = np.array(flp.value)*180/pi
psi         = np.array(psi.value)*180/pi
bank        = np.array(bank.value)*180/pi

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(421)
ax1.plot(m.time,alt,label='Alt')
ax1.plot(m.time,alt_desired,label='Nasa Alt')
# ax1.title.set_text('Altitude (km)')
ax1.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Altitude (km)')
ax1.grid(True)
plt.legend()

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(422)
ax2.plot(m.time,vel,label='Vel')
ax2.plot(m.time,V_desired,label='Nasa Vel')
ax2.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Vel (km/sec)')
ax2.grid(True)
plt.legend()

ax3 = fig.add_subplot(423)
ax3.plot(m.time,latitude)
ax3.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
ax3.set_ylabel('Latitude (deg)')
ax3.grid(True)

ax4 = fig.add_subplot(424)
ax4.plot(m.time,longitude)
ax4.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
ax4.set_ylabel('Longitude (deg)')
ax4.grid(True)


ax5 = fig.add_subplot(425)
ax5.plot(m.time,fpa)
ax5.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
ax5.set_ylabel('FPA (deg)')
ax5.grid(True)

ax6 = fig.add_subplot(426)
ax6.plot(m.time,psi)
ax6.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
ax6.set_ylabel('Azimuth')
ax6.grid(True)

ax8 = fig.add_subplot(427)
ax8.plot(m.time, bank, label='Bank')
ax8.plot(bankTime, bank_desired,label='Nasa Bank')
ax8.set_xlabel('Time (sec)')
ax8.set_ylabel('Bank (Deg)')
ax8.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.suptitle("Apollo 10 Trajectory Matching")
plt.savefig('Apollo10_TrajMatching.png')

plt.show()


# plt.subplot(4,2,1)
# plt.plot(m.time,alt,label='alt')
# plt.plot(m.time,alt_desired, label='Nasa Alt')
# plt.legend()
# plt.subplot(4,2,3)
# plt.plot(m.time,latitude,label='lat')
# plt.legend()
# plt.subplot(4,2,4)
# plt.plot(m.time,longitude,label='lon')
# plt.legend()
# plt.subplot(4,2,2)
# plt.plot(m.time,vel,label='vel')
# plt.plot(m.time,V_desired,label='Nasa Vel')
# plt.legend()
# plt.subplot(4,2,5)
# plt.plot(m.time,fpa,label='fpa')
# plt.legend()
# plt.subplot(4,2,6)
# plt.plot(m.time,psi,label='heading')
# plt.legend()
# plt.subplot(4,2,7)
# plt.plot(m.time,bank,label='bank')
# plt.plot(m.time,bank_desired,label='Nasa Bank')
# plt.xlabel('Time')
# plt.legend()
# plt.show()
```

and State history:

```
Time    Altitude    Time    Velocity    Time    Latitude    Time    Bank Angle
0   123.936 11.8033 11.0962 0.101882    -23.4628    0   0
1.85811 118.083 19.6721 11.0962 9.63964 -23.1728    1   0
5.57432 112.761 33.4426 11.0962 19.1774 -22.8829    2   0
9.29054 108.502 41.3115 11.046  30.6196 -22.5514    3   0
13.0068 103.711 47.2131 10.9958 43.9818 -22.0959    4   0
16.723  99.4519 53.1148 10.8954 55.4318 -21.7231    5   0
18.5811 95.7267 57.0492 10.7448 64.9853 -21.3505    6   0
22.2973 92.5316 62.9508 10.5941 78.3318 -20.9776    7   0
26.0135 88.8046 66.8852 10.4435 85.973  -20.6878    8   0
29.7297 85.6095 70.8197 10.1925 95.4951 -20.4804    9   0
31.5878 82.4163 72.7869 9.94142 105.025 -20.2318    10  0
35.3041 80.285  74.7541 9.74059 112.651 -20.0246    11  0
37.1622 76.5598 78.6885 9.48954 120.284 -19.7761    12  0
40.8784 73.3647 84.5902 9.23849 127.902 -19.6102    13  0
46.4527 70.6998 86.5574 9.08787 135.527 -19.403 14  0
50.1689 67.5047 92.459  8.78661 141.248 -19.2373    15  0
53.8851 64.8415 98.3607 8.53556 148.866 -19.0715    16  0
57.6014 62.1783 104.262 8.28452 154.587 -18.9057    17  0
61.3176 60.0471 112.131 8.03347 160.316 -18.6987    18  0
63.1757 58.9815 118.033 7.88285 173.639 -18.4498    19  0
65.0338 57.3839 125.902 7.6318  183.169 -18.2011    20  0
66.8919 56.8502 131.803 7.48117 192.691 -17.9938    21  0
70.6081 56.3147 141.639 7.23013 202.205 -17.8278    22  0
74.3243 55.2473 149.508 7.02929 209.823 -17.6619    23  0
78.0405 54.7118 159.344 6.77824 219.353 -17.4133    24  0
81.7568 54.7082 169.18  6.42678 226.97  -17.2474    25  0
85.473  54.7046 177.049 6.27615 234.596 -17.0402    26  0
89.1892 55.7648 184.918 6.0251  244.11  -16.8742    27  0
92.9054 56.2931 192.787 5.82427 255.529 -16.6668    28  0
98.4797 57.3516 202.623 5.67364 265.059 -16.4181    29  0
100.338 57.8817 214.426 5.57322 276.477 -16.2106    30  0
107.77  58.4064 224.262 5.4728  289.793 -16.003 31  0
109.628 58.4046 238.033 5.37238 299.307 -15.837 32  0
115.203 58.9311 247.869 5.27197 306.924 -15.6712    33  0
118.919 58.9275 259.672 5.17155 316.423 -15.5878    34  0
122.635 58.392  267.541 5.02092 325.922 -15.5044    35  0
130.068 57.321  275.41  4.9205  331.627 -15.4214    36  0
135.642 57.3156 283.279 4.82008 339.229 -15.3381    37  0
143.074 56.2446 293.115 4.66946 344.927 -15.2964    38  0
148.649 55.7073 300.984 4.46862 352.529 -15.2132    39  0
156.081 55.7001 306.885 4.21757 358.218 -15.2128    40  0
161.655 55.6947 312.787 4.01674 365.82  -15.1295    41  0
169.088 55.6875 316.721 3.91632 371.51  -15.1291    42  0
178.378 56.2105 322.623 3.66527 379.112 -15.0459    43  0
185.811 56.7352 328.525 3.46444 388.603 -15.0039    44  0
191.385 57.2617 334.426 3.16318 396.197 -14.962 45  0
198.818 57.7864 338.361 2.91213 403.783 -14.9614    46  0
206.25  58.8431 342.295 2.7113  413.274 -14.9194    47  0
213.682 59.3678 346.23  2.46025 426.55  -14.9184    48  0
222.973 59.3588 354.098 2.20921 447.412 -14.9168    49  0
226.689 59.8871 356.066 2.05858 466.386 -14.8741    50  0
234.122 59.88   363.934 1.85774 483.455 -14.8728    51  0
243.412 60.4029 369.836 1.60669 504.318 -14.8712    52  0
247.128 59.8674 373.77  1.45607 519.49  -14.8701    53  0
250.845 59.3319 381.639 1.20502 536.559 -14.8688    54  0
256.419 59.3265 387.541 1.00418 549.835 -14.8678    55  0
261.993 58.7892 391.475 0.953975            56  0
269.426 57.7182 399.344 0.803347            57  0
271.284 57.1844 407.213 0.65272             58  0
276.858 56.1152 419.016 0.502092            59  0
282.432 55.5779 430.82  0.401674            60  0
288.007 53.9768 434.754 0.351464            61  0
293.581 52.9076 442.623 0.301255            62  0
297.297 51.3082 452.459 0.251046            63  0
304.73  49.7053 462.295 0.200837            64  0
308.446 48.106  474.098 0.200837            65  0
315.878 46.503  485.902 0.200837            66  0
319.595 45.4356 493.77  0.200837            67  0
321.453 43.8381 503.607 0.200837            68  0
325.169 42.7706 521.311 0.150628            69  0
330.743 41.7014 535.082 0.150628            70  0
334.459 40.634  546.885 0.150628            71  0
341.892 39.563  550.82  0.150628            72  0
349.324 39.0239                 73  0
353.041 37.9564                 74  0
358.615 36.3553                 75  0
364.189 35.2861                 76  0
371.622 33.6832                 77  0
373.48  33.1494                 78  0
377.196 32.6139                 79  0
382.77  30.4809                 80  0
390.203 28.8779                 81  0
395.777 27.8087                 82  0
403.209 25.6739                 83  0
410.642 24.6029                 84  0
416.216 23.0017                 85  0
421.791 21.9325                 86  0
429.223 20.3296                 87  0
431.081 18.732                  88  22.9
438.514 16.5972                 89  22.9
445.946 15.5262                 90  82.1
453.378 14.4551                 91  82.1
458.953 12.854                  92  90
464.527 11.7848                 93  90
468.243 11.2493                 94  90
475.676 9.64635                 95  90
483.108 8.57533                 96  180
488.682 7.50611                 97  180
497.973 6.43329                 98  180
503.547 5.89599                 99  180
512.838 4.82317                 100 180
518.412 4.28587                 101 180
523.986 3.21665                 102 180
531.419 3.20946                 103 180
538.851 3.20227                 104 180
542.568 2.13485                 105 180
550 1.06383                 106 180
                        107 180
                        108 180
                        109 180
                        110 180
                        111 180
                        112 180
                        113 180
                        114 180
                        115 180
                        116 180
                        117 180
                        118 180
                        119 180
                        120 180
                        121 180
                        122 180
                        123 180
                        124 180
                        125 180
                        126 180
                        127 180
                        128 180
                        129 180
                        130 180
                        131 180
                        132 180
                        133 180
                        134 180
                        135 180
                        136 180
                        137 180
                        138 0
                        139 0
                        140 0
                        141 0
                        142 0
                        143 0
                        144 0
                        145 0
                        146 0
                        147 0
                        148 0
                        149 0
                        150 0
                        151 0
                        152 0
                        153 0
                        154 0
                        155 0
                        156 0
                        157 0
                        158 0
                        159 0
                        160 0
                        161 0
                        162 0
                        163 0
                        164 0
                        165 0
                        166 15.4
                        167 15.4
                        168 15.4
                        169 15.4
                        170 41.7
                        171 41.7
                        172 41.7
                        173 41.7
                        174 49.5
                        175 49.5
                        176 49.5
                        177 49.5
                        178 49.5
                        179 49.5
                        180 35.3
                        181 35.3
                        182 32.4
                        183 32.4
                        184 32.4
                        185 32.4
                        186 32.4
                        187 32.4
                        188 32.4
                        189 32.4
                        190 42.4
                        191 42.4
                        192 42.4
                        193 42.4
                        194 42.4
                        195 42.4
                        196 42.4
                        197 42.4
                        198 42.4
                        199 42.4
                        200 51.9
                        201 51.9
                        202 51.9
                        203 51.9
                        204 51.9
                        205 51.9
                        206 51.9
                        207 51.9
                        208 51.9
                        209 51.9
                        210 54.2
                        211 54.2
                        212 54.2
                        213 54.2
                        214 54.2
                        215 54.2
                        216 54.6
                        217 54.6
                        218 -55.3
                        219 -55.3
                        220 -55.3
                        221 -55.3
                        222 -55.3
                        223 -55.3
                        224 -55.3
                        225 -55.3
                        226 -55.3
                        227 -55.3
                        228 -55.3
                        229 -55.3
                        230 -68.3
                        231 -68.3
                        232 -68.3
                        233 -68.3
                        234 -68.3
                        235 -68.3
                        236 -68.3
                        237 -68.3
                        238 -68.3
                        239 -68.3
                        240 -74.2
                        241 -74.2
                        242 -74.2
                        243 -74.2
                        244 -74.2
                        245 -74.2
                        246 -74.2
                        247 -74.2
                        248 -74.2
                        249 -74.2
                        250 -79.3
                        251 -79.3
                        252 -79.3
                        253 -79.3
                        254 -79.3
                        255 -79.3
                        256 -79.3
                        257 -79.3
                        258 -79.3
                        259 -79.3
                        260 -81.1
                        261 -81.1
                        262 -81.1
                        263 -81.1
                        264 -81.1
                        265 -81.1
                        266 -81.1
                        267 -81.1
                        268 -81.1
                        269 -81.1
                        270 -82.3
                        271 -82.3
                        272 -82.3
                        273 -82.3
                        274 -82.3
                        275 -82.3
                        276 -82.3
                        277 -82.3
                        278 -82.3
                        279 -82.3
                        280 -81.9
                        281 -81.9
                        282 -81.9
                        283 -81.9
                        284 -81.9
                        285 -81.9
                        286 -81.9
                        287 -81.9
                        288 -81.9
                        289 -81.9
                        290 -82.3
                        291 -82.3
                        292 -82.3
                        293 -82.3
                        294 -82.3
                        295 -82.3
                        296 -82.3
                        297 -82.3
                        298 -82.3
                        299 -82.3
                        300 -77.2
                        301 -77.2
                        302 -77.2
                        303 -77.2
                        304 -77.2
                        305 -77.2
                        306 -77.2
                        307 -77.2
                        308 -77.2
                        309 -77.2
                        310 -73.5
                        311 -73.5
                        312 -73.5
                        313 -73.5
                        314 -73.5
                        315 -73.5
                        316 -73.5
                        317 -73.5
                        318 -73.5
                        319 -73.5
                        320 -70.4
                        321 -70.4
                        322 -43.7
                        323 -43.7
                        324 -43.7
                        325 -43.7
                        326 -43.7
                        327 -43.7
                        328 -43.7
                        329 -43.7
                        330 -32.1
                        331 -32.1
                        332 -32.1
                        333 -32.1
                        334 -32.1
                        335 -32.1
                        336 -32.1
                        337 -32.1
                        338 -58.8
                        339 -58.8
                        340 62.8
                        341 62.8
                        342 63
                        343 63
                        344 63
                        345 63
                        346 63
                        347 63
                        348 63
                        349 63
                        350 91.9
                        351 91.9
                        352 94
                        353 94
                        354 94
                        355 94
                        356 94
                        357 94
                        358 94
                        359 94
                        360 78.5
                        361 78.5
                        362 78.5
                        363 78.5
                        364 78.5
                        365 78.5
                        366 78.5
                        367 78.5
                        368 78.5
                        369 78.5
                        370 72.5
                        371 72.5
                        372 72.5
                        373 72.5
                        374 72.5
                        375 72.5
                        376 72.5
                        377 72.5
                        378 72.5
                        379 72.5
                        380 64.1
                        381 64.1
                        382 57
                        383 57
                        384 -48.9
                        385 -48.9
                        386 -48.9
                        387 -48.9
                        388 -48.9
                        389 -48.9
                        390 -65.5
                        391 -65.5
                        392 -65.5
                        393 -65.5
                        394 -65.5
                        395 -65.5
                        396 -81.1
                        397 -81.1
                        398 -81.1
                        399 -81.1
                        400 -84.7
                        401 -84.7
                        402 -84.7
                        403 -84.7
                        404 -84.7
                        405 -84.7
                        406 -84.7
                        407 -84.7
                        408 -84.7
                        409 -84.7
                        410 -83.3
                        411 -83.3
                        412 -83.3
                        413 -83.3
                        414 -83.3
                        415 -83.3
                        416 -83.3
                        417 -83.3
                        418 -86
                        419 -86
                        420 -86
                        421 -86
                        422 -86
                        423 -86
                        424 -86
                        425 -86
                        426 -86
                        427 -86
                        428 93.5
                        429 93.5
                        430 102.6
                        431 102.6
                        432 103.4
                        433 103.4
                        434 105
                        435 105
                        436 88.8
                        437 88.8
                        438 88.8
                        439 88.8
                        440 88.8
                        441 88.8
                        442 88.8
                        443 88.8
                        444 88.8
                        445 88.8
                        446 88.8
                        447 88.8
                        448 88.8
                        449 88.8
                        450 88.8
                        451 88.8
                        452 88.8
                        453 88.8
                        454 88.8
                        455 88.8
                        456 88.8
                        457 88.8
                        458 88.8
                        459 88.8
                        460 88.8
                        461 88.8
                        462 88.8
                        463 88.8
                        464 88.8
                        465 88.8
                        466 88.8
                        467 88.8
                        468 88.8
                        469 88.8
                        470 88.8
                        471 88.8
                        472 88.8
                        473 88.8
                        474 88.8
                        475 88.8
                        476 88.8
                        477 88.8
                        478 88.8
                        479 88.8
                        480 88.8
                        481 88.8
                        482 88.8
                        483 88.8
                        484 88.8
                        485 88.8
                        486 88.8
                        487 88.8
                        488 88.8
                        489 88.8
                        490 88.8
                        491 88.8
                        492 88.8
                        493 88.8
                        494 88.8
                        495 88.8
                        496 88.8
                        497 88.8
                        498 0
                        499 0
                        500 0
                        501 0
                        502 0
                        503 0
                        504 0
                        505 0
                        506 0
                        507 0
                        508 0
                        509 0
                        510 0
                        511 0
                        512 0
                        513 0
                        514 0
                        515 0
                        516 0
                        517 0
                        518 0
                        519 0
                        520 0
                        521 0
                        522 0
                        523 0
                        524 0
                        525 0
                        526 0
                        527 0
                        528 0
                        529 0
                        530 0
                        531 0
                        532 0
                        533 0
                        534 0
                        535 0
                        536 0
                        537 0
                        538 0
                        539 0
                        540 0
                        541 0
                        542 0
                        543 0
                        544 0
                        545 0
                        546 0
                        547 0
                        548 0
                        549 0
                        550 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few suggestions to help with troubleshooting and verifying the solution:

1. Plug in the optimal trajectory with `STATUS=0` to fix the MVs and see if the objective function decreases. If the solver reports a successful solution then the [KKT Conditions](https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/KuhnTucker) are satisfied and the solution is optimal if the problem is convex.
2. If the problem is non-convex then try a multi-start method. A multi-start method initializes with different initial conditions to see if a different or better local solution is obtained.
3. Try increasing the number of time steps or the accuracy of those time steps with `m.options.NODES=3`. By default, Gekko uses 2 Nodes per time step. Here is [more information on Nodes](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/OrthogonalCollocation) in APMonitor and Gekko. This grid-independence study is important to verify that there is no solution dependency on the time discretization.

These are some of the main things to try but there are other methods to verify and troubleshoot applications. Let us know if they help.

Comment: Thanks John!  I'll get tryin these right away!

Comment: John, quick folllow up.... how do you use multi-start?  Any examples?

Comment: You can initialize the variables with perturbations to the values. Multi-start also allows you to use parallelization if the runs are independent: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/ParallelComputing

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you for sharing the resource!

Comment: John, I am concerned about the problem setup within Gekko.  Can you take a look at the path constraints specifically? Is this the best way to try to match a trajectory?

Comment: The current path constraint matching is with quadratic objectives such as `m.Minimize(1e3*(r_desired-r)**2)`. An alternative is to use an l1-norm objective for better ranking of prioritization and linearization of the objective. It makes it easier to trade-off objectives and give a `dead-band` around the desired profile. See (1): Estimator tuning: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorTuning (2): Multi-objective optimization: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MultiObjectiveOptimization (3): Objective: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EstimatorObjective for some ideas.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks again for the support! Very excited to be learning Gekko's ins and outs